# exponentially increasing startup time (Spring initialization) on every added DAO interface

Tags: java, spring, performance, mybatis, spring-java-config

During startup, Spring warn-logging shows errors on creating e.g.
"bean with name 'userRepositoryInterface' ... Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required"
During the next few minutes this is repeated many times for each RepositoryInterface, but in the end the the problem is solved and the application works ok.
But the startup time is unacceptable. Besides, when I added a new RepositoryInterface, the startup time expanded to 20 minutes until the server (weblogic 12c) ran out of memory.
The implementing classes of these RepositoryInterfaces are made by Spring/Mybatis (spring 4.1.3, mybatis 3.2.8 and mybatis-spring 1.2.2) that scans (xml) mapper-files to do this.
The repository (DAO) interfaces are autowired in the service-classes calling them, e.g.

```
@Autowired  
private UserRepositoryInterface repository;
```

The repository interfaces are anotated with `@Repository`
I have a `@Configuration` and `@MapperScan` annotated PersistenceConfigurer that contains two `@Bean` methods:

- DataSource dataSource()
- SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource)

The dataSource and sqlSessionFactory are not called until the end of the startup process, that seems to be the problem.
I tried to change that by adding `@Order(0)` to the PersistenceConfigurer, but this had no effect.   Moving the two Beans to other Configuration classes also had no positive effect.
For Spring I use Java configuration, no xml.
In response to comments, here is the whole PersistenceConfigurer:

```
package org.xx.xxxxxxx.configuration;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * This class configures the application's persistence layer.
 */
@Configuration
@MapperScan(basePackages = "org.xx.xxxxxxx.repository")
public class PersistenceConfigurer {
    static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(PersistenceConfigurer.class);
    @Value("${jdbc.datasource}")
    private String jdbcDatasource;   // in jdbc.properties: jdbc.datasource=jdbc/OurDS

@Value("classpath*:sqlmapper/*.xml")
private Resource[] mapperFiles;

@Value("classpath:mybatisConfig.xml")
private Resource myBatisConfig;

/**
 * @return The configured data source.
 */
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
    DataSource dataSource = null;
    LOGGER.debug("Configuring datasource creating datasource with jndiname " + jdbcDatasource);
    try {
        // this works for weblogic,  but not for Tomcat
        dataSource = (DataSource) jndiTemplate.lookup(jdbcDatasource);
        LOGGER.debug("Configuring datasource successfully created datasource " + dataSource);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Configuring datasource error creating datasource NamingException " + jdbcDatasource);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Configuring datasource error creating datasource " + jdbcDatasource);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dataSource;
}

/**
 * @param dataSource A configured data source.
 * @return The SQL session factory bean for data management.
 */
@Bean
public SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LOGGER.debug("sqlSessionFactory making SqlSessionFactoryBean with datasource " + dataSource);
    SqlSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factoryBean.setMapperLocations(mapperFiles);
    factoryBean.setConfigLocation(myBatisConfig);
    return factoryBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: How you are creating dataSource JNDI lookup or create connection pool locally?

Comment: JNDI lookup. The application can be deployed for different "owners". The weblogic server administrator installs the datasource files and the wars.

Comment: hmm...... Then that is the problem, its worth looking once the spring configuration file. Can you post your configuration file and weblogic JNDI name. I had similar issue....... it was miss configuration of JNDI

Comment: If you mean Spring configuration file: we use Java configuration only. Or do you mean a datasource-file?  In the PersistenceConfigurer there is:     @Value("${jdbc.datasource}")
    private String jdbcDatasource;   // in jdbc.properties: jdbc.datasource=jdbc/OurDS. That seems to be found alright, no NamingException or other Exception.

Comment: Yes Java Configuration

Comment: I added the PersistenceConfigurer code above

Comment: For completeness: I temporarily changed the code of the PersistenceConfigurer: no JNDI lookup/datasourcefile but getting data like userid and password from the jdbc.properties file. The effect is the same.

Comment: I don't use MyBatis but it looks like you added the mapper data twice (once with `@MapperScan` and once with `factoryBean.setMapperLocations(mapperFiles)`. Is that a problem?

Comment: No, the two configurations are necessary, one points to the RepositorInterface Java classses, the other to the queries in mapperfiles. Removing the first one makes deployment impossible, removing the second one makes deployment faster, but leads to errors runtime: the queries are not found/performed.

Comment: where are you importing propertysource(properties file) are you importing it other configuration class?

Comment: application.properties (only item is applicationPath), jdbc.properties and 2 message.properties.
All referred to in the `@Configuration` annotated `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, the message-files in its `@Bean` annotated `MessageSource`, the other two in its `@Bean` annotated `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Comment: You could try injecting Properties to PersistenceConfigurer directly, I believe since webMvc is child context of application context. PersistenceConfigurer might not get these properties

Comment: We tried hardcoding the properties in the PersistenceConfigurer. It had no effect.

Comment: But it had effect once we also changed 'SqlSessionFactoryBean' to 'SqlSessionFactory'. This worked only in combination of hardcoding the properties. We try to get around that too, trying to get the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer to be made earlier. To be continued...

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine found the main solution: not to return `SqlSessionFactoryBean` but `SqlSessionFactory`.
Before this solution the startup-time depended on the number of RepositoryInterfaces:
5 RepositoryInterfaces: 12 seconds, 6: > 80 seconds; 7: 9 minutes ending in memory problems.
After, it is always 9 seconds.

This solution did not work immediately, because thanks to the fix, now the creation is so early, that it precedes the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer creation declared in the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.
So we put the resolving of the properties needed directly in the PersistenceConfigurer. Thank you, Karthik for this suggestion.

The changed code in the PersistenceConfigurer:
added imports:
`import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;`
`import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;`

3 changed private variables (now all 3 are simple Strings, without `@Value` annotation) :

```
private String jdbcDatasource = "jdbc/OurDS";  // moved away from jdbc.properties (was only property left there)

private String mapperFilesLocation = "classpath*:sqlmapper/*.xml";

private String myBatisConfigLocation = "classpath:mybatisConfig.xml";
```

One changed method, the main change is the returned object. Three lines for the property-resolving are added.

```
/**
 * @param dataSource A configured data source.
 * @return The SQL session factory (org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory).
 * @throws Exception on sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject(), IOException on resolver.getResources 
 */
@Bean
public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
    LOGGER.debug("sqlSessionFactory making SqlSessionFactoryBean with datasource " + dataSource);
    SqlSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    Resource[] mapperFiles = resolver.getResources(mapperFilesLocation);
    Resource myBatisConfig = resolver.getResource(myBatisConfigLocation);   
    factoryBean.setMapperLocations(mapperFiles);
    factoryBean.setConfigLocation(myBatisConfig);
    return factoryBean.getObject();
}
```